# Installing cURL properly on OpenWRT Chaos Calmer (15.05.1) for ar71xx TP-LINK MR3020

Tags: router, curl, openwrt, opkg

I installed cURL [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489729/openwrt-curl-on-mr-3020) on OpenWRT, as I also hadn't enough disk space available on the router, but when I tried to run it, it said:

```sh
# curl
curl: can't load library 'libmbedtls.so.9'
```

Okay, so just install libmbedtls, right? But it is not part of [this repository](http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/packages/base). I found out that it's present on [this repository](http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/packages/mipsel_24kc/base), so I tried to add it as a custom repo at `/etc/opkg/customfeeds.conf` and add mipsel_24kc as a custom architecture at `/etc/opkg.conf`, by appending a line `arch mipsel_24kc 100` at the end of the file, hoping that mipsel_24kc would be compatible with ar71xx, but everything I got was a wall of text on my terminal every time I ran any opkg command with each line saying:

```sh
Package <package_name> version <version> has no valid architecture, ignoring.
```

And, to worsen it, it has all the dependencies installed, but still waits for a libmbedtls library that doesn't exist on the repository.

```sh
# opkg depends curl
curl depends on:
    libc
    libcurl

# opkg install libc
Package libc (0.9.33.2-1) installed in root is up to date.

# opkg install libcurl
Package libcurl (7.40.0-3) installed in root is up to date.

# curl
curl: can't load library 'libmbedtls.so.9'
```

Also, I can't update this OS. Any ideas about how to solve this issue?